# Can the keyword 'this' be used to refer the timer insider setInterval method in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I already know that the `setInterval` function in javascript executes a function or a block of code repeatedly every fixed amount of time. I already know that its syntax is as follows:

```
setInterval(func|code, [delay], [arg1], [arg2], ...)
```

My question is: can i use the keyword 'this' as an argument to refer the timer id (all arguments in my case are passed as arguments of an external callback function)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  `const timeout = setTimeout( () => console.log('inside, this=', this), 1000); console.log(timeout);` Same with `setInterval`

Comment: No. when using a regular function, the `this` keyword inside that function will refer to the execution scope once the function runs. Which will be `window` in the browser. When using an arrow function `this` will refer to the declaration scope (so, "whatever the scope is when the parser sees that line and stores for running later"). Also, _never_ use `setInterval` with string content. It's a huge security risk, because it's just another form of `eval()` and most servers have CSP in place to disallow this, so even if you do use it, it won't even work. Stick to function handles.

Comment: "*can i use the keyword 'this' as an argument to refer the timer*" it's not really clear what you mean by "the timer". Is it the timer *id*? The callback? The actual timer that JS uses for delayed execition? Something else? The answer is "no" in all cases but at least we can offer alternatives for some of these. We'd probably still need more context for what you're actually trying to do, however.

Comment: I am trying to pass 'this' as an argument of the callback function. My callback function clear the interval when a criterion holds. That is what I ask for. @VLAZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly pass the ID of the timer before it's created. Problem is that you have to *call* `setInterval` in order to get an ID in order to actually pass it along to the called function:

```js
let timerId = setInterval(function() {}, 1000, timerId);
//error - we are using `timerId` before its declaration is finished
```

### Pass an object

However, you can take advantage of the way objects work where the same reference is shared. So, you can initialise an object, which means the variable *exists*, then call `setInterval` and record the timer ID as a property of the object. Then pass that object to the callback as argument. By the time the callback executes, the object property is sure to be populated and you can just use the value from it:

```js
let cb;

{ //callback in one scope
  
  //simple counter that stops at zero
  let i = 3;
  cb = timerContext => {
    console.log(i--);
    if (i < 0) {
      console.log("finish");
      clearInterval(timerContext.timerId);
    }
  }
}


{//start the timer in a different scope
  let context = { timerId: null };
  
  context.timerId = setInterval(cb, 1000, context);
}
```

### Create a wrapper

Alternatively, you can only pass the external callback a timer ID if you create a wrapper function for it when you call `setInterval:

```js
let cb;

{ //callback in one scope
  
  //simple counter that stops at zero
  let i = 3;
  cb = timerId => {
    console.log(i--);
    if (i < 0) {
      console.log("finish");
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  }
}


{//start the timer in a different scope
  let timerId = setInterval(() => cb(timerId), 1000);
}
```

### Pass as `this`

If you prefer, you can pass the timer ID as the `this` context in either fashion, if your callback is a normal function:

#### Object

```js
let cb;

{ //callback in one scope
  
  //simple counter that stops at zero
  let i = 3;
  cb = function() {
    console.log(i--);
    if (i < 0) {
      console.log("finish");
      clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }
  }
}


{//start the timer in a different scope
  let context = { timerId: null };
  
  context.timerId = setInterval(cb.bind(context), 1000);
}
```

#### Just the ID

```js
let cb;

{ //callback in one scope
  
  //simple counter that stops at zero
  let i = 3;
  cb = function() {
    console.log(i--);
    if (i < 0) {
      console.log("finish");
      clearInterval(this);
    }
  }
}


{//start the timer in a different scope
  let timerId = setInterval(() => cb.call(timerId), 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used a wrapper as you mentioned and it worked fine with me.